# javascript for loop with dynamic div id

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, for-loop

this works to create a second pull down menu dynamically based on the result of the first pull down menu:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    $('#wdiv' + i).change(function() {
        var wdiv = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "populate_classes.php",
            data: 'theOption=' + wdiv,
            success: function(whatigot) {
                $('#class_list' + i).html(whatigot);
            } 

        }); //END $.ajax
    }); //END dropdown change event 
}
```

why does the input from drop down select #wdiv0 change the drop down menu #class_list1?  I want the #wdiv selection to set the #classlist0 drop down select.

Here is the portion of the form:

```
<fieldset><legend>Select Divisions</legend>              
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><u><strong>Name</strong></u></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><u><strong>Division</strong></u></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><u><strong>Class</strong></u></div></td>
  </tr>
  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $wrestlerkey; $i++) {    
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tourn_division AS td WHERE t_num = ?';
      $divresult = $dbConnect->fetchAll($sql, $_SESSION['tourn_id']);
      $divcount = count($divresult);
  ?>          
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="right"><?php echo $_SESSION['wfirst'][$i] . " " . $_SESSION['wlast'][$i] . ":"; ?></div></td>
      <td>
        <select name="<?php echo "wdiv" . $i ?>" id="<?php echo "wdiv" . $i ?>">
        <?php for ($d = 0; $d < $divcount; $d++) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $divresult[$d]->div_num; ?>"><?php echo $divresult[$d]->div_name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>  
      </select></td>
      <td>
      <div id="<?php echo "class_list" . $i ?>"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because the AJAX callback handlers you create both share a reference to the same variable "i". To avoid that, you can create your "success" handler with a separate function *edit* — in fact, due to the nature of your code structure here, you need to make the whole "change" callback in a separate function:

```
function makeChangeHandler(listIndex) {
  return function() {
    var wdiv = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "populate_classes.php",
        data: 'theOption=' + wdiv,
        success: function(whatigot) {
            $('#class_list' + listIndex).html(whatigot);
        } 
     });
  };
}

// ...

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // for 2, substitute actual number of elements involved
    $('#wdiv' + i).change( makeChangeHandler(i) );
}
```

That function will return the actual handler function. Each such function returned by "makeSuccessHandler" will have it's very own private **copy** of the loop index.

(Note edits made - the whole "change" handler needs to be constructed in the helper function.)

Comment: as long as you make that success handler before being inside the change function, this should work

Comment: @JaimeMorales ooo good point!!  I was working on adding back more of the original code anyway. Thanks!

Comment: do i put makeSuccesshandler prior to or inside the for loop?

Comment: @MattKeel somewhere outside the loop would be best.

Comment: OK, with above code setting #wdiv0 properly sets the new drop-down #class_list0 successfully.  However, setting #wdiv1 has no effect on #class_list1

Comment: i changed the for loop to i < 2 and the second row #wdiv1 successfully changes drop-down #class_list1...  is that the correct way to fix it?

Comment: @MattKeel yes sorry I didn't notice that; as your loop was originally written, it would stop after the first iteration (when "i" is zero). Your fix is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

The ajax response is returning after the loop has finished, so it will always be the last value of i. You need to set a variable to i or put a closure around it:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
       var currentIndex = i; // this will not work (see comments below)
        $('#wdiv' + i).change({currentIndex: i}, function(e) {
            var wdiv = $(this).val();
            var currentIndex = e.data.currentIndex;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "populate_classes.php",
                data: 'theOption=' + wdiv,
                success: function(whatigot) {
                    $('#class_list' + currentIndex).html(whatigot);
                } 

            }); //END $.ajax
        }); //END dropdown change event 
    }
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   (function (i){
        $('#wdiv' + i).change(function() {
            var wdiv = $(this).val();

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "populate_classes.php",
                data: 'theOption=' + wdiv,
                success: function(whatigot) {
                    $('#class_list' + i).html(whatigot);
                } 

              }); //END $.ajax

        }); //END dropdown change event 
      })(i);
    }
```

Comment: That won't work, for the very same reason that using plain "i" won't work. The "currentIndex" variable isn't initialized until the "change" handler is actually called :)

Comment: `currentIndex` needs to be set outside of the function.

Comment: Still won't work, though your anonymous function version is fine. JavaScript variables are strictly scoped at the function level.

Comment: Because that local variable "currentIndex" is scoped exactly the same way that "i" is scoped.  Thus, each of those event handlers has a reference to the exact same variable in the closure, so its value will be the same as "i" when the loop is finished.

Comment: yep. you are right. for this instance, I might want to use the event data to pass the correct index to the change function